# SQL Statement to eliminate duplicates based on value in another column

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have data that is in two tables and I have a query combining the data as below. I am trying to eliminate duplicates based on the Id column where I pick the record with the oldest split date. Could anyone kindly assist me with the SQL statement to effect this?

```
|ID     |SecID  |ReportingDate  |SplitDate  |Adjustor|  
|1465   |2      |31-Dec-09      |01-Nov-10  |0.1     |  
|1465   |2      |31-Dec-09      |27-Dec-12  |0.2     |  
|1466   |2      |31-Dec-10      |27-Dec-12  |0.2     |   
|1468   |2      |31-Dec-11      |27-Dec-12  |0.2     |  
|1469   |2      |31-Dec-08      |01-Nov-10  |0.1     |  
|1469   |2      |31-Dec-08      |27-Dec-12  |0.2     |
```

The result should be as below:

```
|ID     |SecId  |ReportingDate  |Adjustor  |  
|1469   |2      |31-Dec-08      |0.1       |  
|1465   |2      |31-Dec-09      |0.1       |  
|1466   |2      |31-Dec-10      |0.2       |  
|1468   |2      |31-Dec-11      |0.2       |
```

More Information:
Let me explain what I am trying to do here.

In the fundamentals table I have a row with a unique Line Id, secId( a product identifier) and a reporting date for this line.
This information needs to be adjusted using information from the splitdetails table that has a date from which it becomes applicable, the secId(product) it affects and the adjustor ratio to be used.

For each line in fundamentals table:
-Where any secId that doesnt have an entry in the splits table, adjustor should be 1.
-If secId is present in the Splits table, the split to be used is the oldest one whose date is older than the fundamentals table reporting date being checked.

I am hoping to get results from the sample above would end up look like this:
|     ID    |SecId      |ReportingDate      |Adjustor  |
|1469       2   31-Dec-08   0.1
|1465       2   31-Dec-09   0.1
|1466       2   31-Dec-10   0.2
|1468       2   31-Dec-11   0.2
|1467       2   31-Dec-12   1

The query I am using is
         SELECT Gotten.ID, Gotten.SecID, Gotten.ReportingDate, Gotten.SplitDate, Adjustor
  FROM
(SELECT tblFundamentalsDetails.id, tblFundamentalsDetails.SecId,   tblFundamentalsDetails.ReportingDate, tblSplitDetails.SplitDate, tblSplitDetails.Adjustor 
FROM tblFundamentalsDetails
LEFT JOIN tblSplitDetails
ON (tblFundamentalsDetails.ReportingDate

Comment: Is there any relationship between two tables? I think this relationship  is needed for deleting the duplicate rows in the first table.

Comment: @NaserE My apologies for the delay in replying.
I am not trying to delete, I am trying to filter out the duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach, that should be ok in Access SQL (though you might need to change the aliases):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT ID, sdate = min(SplitDate)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ID
) b
ON a.ID = b.ID
AND a.SplitDate = b.sdate
```

Also you could take the inner query and make its own qry in Access.

Comment: Access doesn't support the `sdate = min(SplitDate)` syntax in a column list.

Comment: hence the aliases comment:)

Comment: @cjb110 this works as per my example, thank you very much. Any chance this can extend to showing 1 for adjustor whenever splitdate is null?

Comment: @GordThompson I tried the  'sdate = min(SplitDate)' , didnt work, I figured I would run it as an alias as a placeholder, then I saw the last bit of advice :-)

Comment: a column like: iif(isnull([SplitDate]), 1, [Adjustor]) as [Adjustor] should do it.

Comment: Got out of bed to try the idea to use your earlier statement and union that with a query where splitdate is null and it has brought the exact result I needed. Finally! Thank you. Now back to sleep!

Answer (score 1):

For test data in a table (or saved query) named [Source]

```
ID    SecID  ReportingDate  SplitDate   Adjustor
----  -----  -------------  ----------  --------
1465      2  2009-12-31     2010-11-01       0.1
1465      2  2009-12-31     2012-12-27       0.2
1466      2  2010-12-31     2012-12-27       0.2
1468      2  2011-12-31     2012-12-27       0.2
1469      2  2008-12-31     2010-11-01       0.1
1469      2  2008-12-31     2012-12-27       0.2
```

the following query has been tested and *actually does work in Access*:

```sql
SELECT 
    Source.ID,
    Source.SecID,
    Source.ReportingDate,
    Source.Adjustor
FROM
    Source
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT ID, MIN(SplitDate) AS MinOfSplitDate
        FROM Source
        GROUP BY ID
    ) AS MinDate
        ON MinDate.ID = Source.ID
            AND MinDate.MinOfSplitDate = Source.SplitDate
```

returning

```
ID    SecID  ReportingDate  Adjustor
----  -----  -------------  --------
1465      2  2009-12-31          0.1
1466      2  2010-12-31          0.2
1468      2  2011-12-31          0.2
1469      2  2008-12-31          0.1
```

Comment: This works as per my example, thank you very much. Any chance this can extend to showing 1 for adjustor whenever splitdate is null?

Answer (score 0):

I can do this on MySQL server, if I understood you this is what you need:

```
DELETE t1 FROM mytable t1, mytable t2 WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID 
AND t1.ReportingDate < t2.ReportingDate
```

This will only keep rows in mytable with the newest date and same id

Notice that three rows with same ID will become just one. You'll only keep one row for each ID.