# What SQL can I use to retrieve counts from my payments data?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, count

Count criteria: A "true" count, by month-year, of the number of students (indexed by a unique Student ID) at each School by School Service Type.

I am currently using MS-Access. I need to be able to extract counts for a database with similar data as the sample data below. Each row is a payment observation.

Sample data:

```
Student ID |  School  | School Service Type | PaymentStartDate | PaymentEndDate |
   001          ABC              ED             01/02/2010         02/04/2012
   001          ABC              ED             01/02/2010         01/05/2010
   001          ABC              ED             04/02/2010         05/05/2010            
   001          DEF              EZ             01/02/2010         02/04/2012
   001                           RR             02/02/2012         02/03/2012
   002          ABC              ED             02/02/2010         02/03/2011
   002          ABC              EZ             02/02/2010         06/03/2010
   002          GHI              ED             02/04/2011         02/04/2012
   003          ABC              ED             02/02/2011         02/03/2012
   003          DEF              ED             01/02/2010         08/03/2010
   003                           RR             02/02/2011         02/03/2011
   004                           RR             02/02/2011         02/03/2011
   005          GHI              ED             08/02/2010         02/04/2011
   006          GHI              ED             08/02/2010         08/02/2010
```

What I want my count to look like:

```
  Month  |  Year  | School | ED | EZ | RR |

   01       2010     ABC      1    0    0    
   01       2010     DEF      1    1    0
   01       2010     GHI      0    0    0
   02       2010     ABC      2    1    0
   03       2010     ABC      2    1    0
```

**Example**

Desire: I want a true count of students, across schools, by service type, for `January 2010`

Biggest hurdle - Duplicates

Please take a look at the observations for `Student ID 001`. Between January 2010 and February 2012, School `ABC` received 3 payments for the exact same `Service Type (ED)` for Student 001.

I want my January 2010 count of students that received `ED` services at school `ABC` to return a value of 1, since only one student (`Student 001`) received services for `ED` at that school for that time.

However, when I conduct a crosstab to retrieve my counts with this data as it is, it returns a value of 2 (for two students). The reason being that both payment #1 and payment #2 of `Student 001` meet my month-year criteria of January 2010.

**Payment #1** meets the criteria because January 2010 lies within the payment date range of 01/02/2010 - 02/04/2012*.

**Payment #2** also meets the criteria because January 2010 lies within the payment date range of 01/02/2010 - 01/05/2010.

**Payment #3** does not meet the criteria because January 2010 is not within the date range for that row (04/02/2010 - 05/05/2010).

*You get these dates from the `PaymentStartDate` and `PaymentEndDate` respectively.

I prepared an Excel version of the sample data here:[Link to Excel file](http://tinyurl.com/oqvx2ru)

Please keep in mind that:

- The time elapsed between the PaymentStartDate and PaymentEndDate is extremely variable across the board, and ranges from 0 days to 122 days.
- Many times, there are truly unique payment observations where the time lapsed between PaymentStartDate and PaymentEndDate is 0 days (take a look at the payment row for Student ID 006 in the data above). Therefore, getting rid of rows that do not meet a specified "time lapsed between PaymentStartDate and PaymentEndDate" criteria is not an option, since many times they are not the duplicates I am trying to get rid of for my counts.
- Yes, for certain Service Types, there is no School value.

As always, any helpful ideas of advice on how I can resolve this duplicates issue, and retrieve my true count values within MS-Access are greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Edit (02/10/2014): Changed the count output above to reflect the sample data I provided in my post. My apologies for not doing so before.

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547512/sql-statement-to-eliminate-duplicates-based-on-value-in-another-column/21548990?noredirect=1#21548990 Maybe you will get a few ideas?

Comment: I don't see data for result  01 2010 DEF  2  1  0.  Specifically the ED column should be only 1? Also, for this student census do they get counted if they were paying at any time during the month? Or only if they were paying on the first of the month? e.g. start=1/31/10 and stop=2/1/2010 would count in two months or only one month?  Also, does the tinyurl.xls correspond to the results above? tkx

Comment: @Avagut: I will certainly check it out.

Comment: @donPablo: I made the necessary changes in my post so that the count output matches what is in the sample data above. For the census, they are counted if they were paying at any time during the month. So start-1/31/2010 end-2/1/2010 would count in two months. The tinyurl.xls is an Excel file of the sample data. It should now (2/10/2014) correspond to the count output above.

Comment: That third row of sample data clearly does not apply for January 2010 totals, but would it count toward the totals for both April 2010 and May 2010 (since the StartDate is in April and the EndDate is in May)?

Comment: @GordThompson: Yes, the row you are referring to would count towards both April and May 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to tackle it. For sample data in a table named [Payments]

```
Payment Row  Student ID  School  School Service Type  PaymentStartDate  PaymentEndDate
-----------  ----------  ------  -------------------  ----------------  --------------
          1  001         ABC     ED                   2010-01-02        2012-02-04    
          2  001         ABC     ED                   2010-01-02        2010-01-05    
          3  001         ABC     ED                   2010-04-02        2010-05-05    
          4  001         DEF     EZ                   2010-01-02        2012-02-04    
          5  001                 RR                   2012-02-02        2012-02-03    
          6  002         ABC     ED                   2010-02-02        2011-02-03    
          7  002         ABC     EZ                   2010-02-02        2010-06-03    
          8  002         GHI     ED                   2011-02-04        2012-02-04    
          9  003         ABC     ED                   2011-02-02        2012-02-03    
         10  003         DEF     ED                   2010-01-02        2010-08-03    
         11  003                 RR                   2011-02-02        2011-02-03    
         12  004                 RR                   2011-02-02        2011-02-03    
         13  005         GHI     ED                   2010-08-02        2011-02-04    
         14  006         GHI     ED                   2010-08-02        2010-08-02
```

if we create a saved query in Access named [PaymentsYearMonth]

```sql
SELECT 
    [Student ID], 
    School, 
    [School Service Type], 
    (Year(PaymentStartDate) * 100) + Month(PaymentStartDate) AS StartYYYYMM, 
    (Year(PaymentEndDate) * 100) + Month(PaymentEndDate) AS EndYYYYMM
FROM Payments
```

it will give us

```
Student ID  School  School Service Type  StartYYYYMM  EndYYYYMM
----------  ------  -------------------  -----------  ---------
001         ABC     ED                        201001     201202
001         ABC     ED                        201001     201001
001         ABC     ED                        201004     201005
001         DEF     EZ                        201001     201202
001                 RR                        201202     201202
002         ABC     ED                        201002     201102
002         ABC     EZ                        201002     201006
002         GHI     ED                        201102     201202
003         ABC     ED                        201102     201202
003         DEF     ED                        201001     201008
003                 RR                        201102     201102
004                 RR                        201102     201102
005         GHI     ED                        201008     201102
006         GHI     ED                        201008     201008
```

To generate the Year/Month pairs that the data covers, we can use a table named [MonthNumbers]

```
MonthNumber
-----------
          1
          2
          3
          4
          5
          6
          7
          8
          9
         10
         11
         12
```

and a table named [YearNumbers] which covers every year that might possibly appear in the data. For safety one might include every year from, say, 1901 to 2525, but for illustration we'll just use

```
YearNumber
----------
      2009
      2010
      2011
      2012
      2013
```

Now we can create a saved query named [MonthsToReport] to give us the rows that might have results

```sql
SELECT
    yn.YearNumber,
    mn.MonthNumber,
    (yn.YearNumber * 100) + mn.MonthNumber AS YYYYMM
FROM
    YearNumbers AS yn,
    MonthNumbers AS mn
WHERE ((yn.YearNumber * 100) + mn.MonthNumber)>=DMin("StartYYYYMM","PaymentsYearMonth")
    AND ((yn.YearNumber * 100) + mn.MonthNumber)<=DMax("EndYYYYMM","PaymentsYearMonth")
```

Sorted by Year and Month that would look like

```
YearNumber  MonthNumber  YYYYMM
----------  -----------  ------
      2010            1  201001
      2010            2  201002
      2010            3  201003
      2010            4  201004
      2010            5  201005
      2010            6  201006
      2010            7  201007
      2010            8  201008
      2010            9  201009
      2010           10  201010
      2010           11  201011
      2010           12  201012
      2011            1  201101
      2011            2  201102
      2011            3  201103
      2011            4  201104
      2011            5  201105
      2011            6  201106
      2011            7  201107
      2011            8  201108
      2011            9  201109
      2011           10  201110
      2011           11  201111
      2011           12  201112
      2012            1  201201
      2012            2  201202
```

Now to create a query that gives us distinct instances of Year/Month/Student/School/Type

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    mtr.YearNumber,
    mtr.MonthNumber,
    pym.[Student ID],
    pym.School,
    pym.[School Service Type]
FROM
    MonthsToReport AS mtr
    INNER JOIN
    PaymentsYearMonth AS pym
        ON mtr.YYYYMM>=pym.StartYYYYMM 
            AND mtr.YYYYMM<=pym.EndYYYYMM
```

...wrap that in an aggregation query to count up the (now unique) [Student ID] values

```sql
SELECT
    YearNumber,
    MonthNumber,
    School,
    [School Service Type],
    COUNT(*) AS CountOfStudents
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            mtr.YearNumber,
            mtr.MonthNumber,
            pym.[Student ID],
            pym.School,
            pym.[School Service Type]
        FROM
            MonthsToReport AS mtr
            INNER JOIN
            PaymentsYearMonth AS pym
                ON mtr.YYYYMM>=pym.StartYYYYMM 
                    AND mtr.YYYYMM<=pym.EndYYYYMM
    ) AS distinctQuery
GROUP BY 
    YearNumber,
    MonthNumber,
    School,
    [School Service Type]
```

and then use *that* as the FROM subquery in our crosstab query

```sql
TRANSFORM Nz(First(CountOfStudents),0) AS n
SELECT 
    YearNumber,
    MonthNumber,
    School
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            YearNumber,
            MonthNumber,
            School,
            [School Service Type],
            COUNT(*) AS CountOfStudents
        FROM
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    mtr.YearNumber,
                    mtr.MonthNumber,
                    pym.[Student ID],
                    pym.School,
                    pym.[School Service Type]
                FROM
                    MonthsToReport AS mtr
                    INNER JOIN
                    PaymentsYearMonth AS pym
                        ON mtr.YYYYMM>=pym.StartYYYYMM 
                            AND mtr.YYYYMM<=pym.EndYYYYMM
            ) AS distinctQuery
        GROUP BY 
            YearNumber,
            MonthNumber,
            School,
            [School Service Type]
    ) AS countQuery
GROUP BY
    YearNumber,
    MonthNumber,
    School
PIVOT [School Service Type]
```

returning

```
YearNumber  MonthNumber  School  ED  EZ  RR
----------  -----------  ------  --  --  --
      2010            1  ABC     1   0   0 
      2010            1  DEF     1   1   0 
      2010            2  ABC     2   1   0 
      2010            2  DEF     1   1   0 
      2010            3  ABC     2   1   0 
      2010            3  DEF     1   1   0 
      2010            4  ABC     2   1   0 
      2010            4  DEF     1   1   0 
      2010            5  ABC     2   1   0 
      2010            5  DEF     1   1   0 
      2010            6  ABC     2   1   0 
      2010            6  DEF     1   1   0 
      2010            7  ABC     2   0   0 
      2010            7  DEF     1   1   0 
      2010            8  ABC     2   0   0 
      2010            8  DEF     1   1   0 
      2010            8  GHI     2   0   0 
      2010            9  ABC     2   0   0 
      2010            9  DEF     0   1   0 
      2010            9  GHI     1   0   0 
      2010           10  ABC     2   0   0 
      2010           10  DEF     0   1   0 
      2010           10  GHI     1   0   0 
      2010           11  ABC     2   0   0 
      2010           11  DEF     0   1   0 
      2010           11  GHI     1   0   0 
      2010           12  ABC     2   0   0 
      2010           12  DEF     0   1   0 
      2010           12  GHI     1   0   0 
      2011            1  ABC     2   0   0 
      2011            1  DEF     0   1   0 
      2011            1  GHI     1   0   0 
      2011            2          0   0   2 
      2011            2  ABC     3   0   0 
      2011            2  DEF     0   1   0 
      2011            2  GHI     2   0   0 
      2011            3  ABC     2   0   0 
      2011            3  DEF     0   1   0 
      2011            3  GHI     1   0   0 
      2011            4  ABC     2   0   0 
      2011            4  DEF     0   1   0 
      2011            4  GHI     1   0   0 
      2011            5  ABC     2   0   0 
      2011            5  DEF     0   1   0 
      2011            5  GHI     1   0   0 
      2011            6  ABC     2   0   0 
      2011            6  DEF     0   1   0 
      2011            6  GHI     1   0   0 
      2011            7  ABC     2   0   0 
      2011            7  DEF     0   1   0 
      2011            7  GHI     1   0   0 
      2011            8  ABC     2   0   0 
      2011            8  DEF     0   1   0 
      2011            8  GHI     1   0   0 
      2011            9  ABC     2   0   0 
      2011            9  DEF     0   1   0 
      2011            9  GHI     1   0   0 
      2011           10  ABC     2   0   0 
      2011           10  DEF     0   1   0 
      2011           10  GHI     1   0   0 
      2011           11  ABC     2   0   0 
      2011           11  DEF     0   1   0 
      2011           11  GHI     1   0   0 
      2011           12  ABC     2   0   0 
      2011           12  DEF     0   1   0 
      2011           12  GHI     1   0   0 
      2012            1  ABC     2   0   0 
      2012            1  DEF     0   1   0 
      2012            1  GHI     1   0   0 
      2012            2          0   0   1 
      2012            2  ABC     2   0   0 
      2012            2  DEF     0   1   0 
      2012            2  GHI     1   0   0
```