# How does the following code read and look in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, ms-access, jet

```
 The code originates from the following post:
```

[What SQL can I use to retrieve counts from my payments data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633961/what-sql-can-i-use-to-retrieve-counts-from-my-payments-data)

I am working with a large amount of data, and this code (in MS-ACCESS JET SQL) currently takes about 10-15 minutes to query (when it doesn't crash). I want to increase the speed in which my query runs, which is why I am looking to utilize the pass through query approach. Currently, the back end database I use is SQL Server (2012), which I use an ODBC connection to link to.

I am under the impression that writing your SQL in the back end database's language allows the pass through query to perform more efficiently. I believe that T-SQL would be the language. I have done the research, and there really is no "JET-SQL to T-SQL converter". Therefore, I kindly ask if anyone has any suggestions on how the following code reads and looks in T-SQL.

```
    TRANSFORM Nz(First(CountOfStudents),0) AS n
SELECT 
    YearNumber,
    MonthNumber,
    School
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            YearNumber,
            MonthNumber,
            School,
            [School Service Type],
            COUNT(*) AS CountOfStudents
        FROM
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    mtr.YearNumber,
                    mtr.MonthNumber,
                    pym.[Student ID],
                    pym.School,
                    pym.[School Service Type]
                FROM
                    MonthsToReport AS mtr
                    INNER JOIN
                    PaymentsYearMonth AS pym
                        ON mtr.YYYYMM>=pym.StartYYYYMM 
                            AND mtr.YYYYMM<=pym.EndYYYYMM
            ) AS distinctQuery
        GROUP BY 
            YearNumber,
            MonthNumber,
            School,
            [School Service Type]
    ) AS countQuery
GROUP BY
    YearNumber,
    MonthNumber,
    School
PIVOT [School Service Type]
```

As always, thank you for your time.

Comment: Is your specific question "how can I make this query perform faster"?  If you're using SQL Server Management Studio then when you execute the query you can examine the query execution plan, which will help you debug the query's performance.  You can identify parts of the execution plan which involve heavy CPU work (such as table scans) or too many records being passed around.  From there you can target performance improvements where there are actual performance problems.

Comment: @David:Currently, when I use SQL Server Management Studio, I get errors when attempting to run the query I provided above. The reason I believe this is the case is that the query is currently written in MS-Access's native SQL (JET SQL), which the back end SQL Server is not able to read (without MS Access translating it).

Comment: change `nz` to `coalesce` and try again. `nz` is VBA coming into your query. `coalesce` is the T-SQL equivalent.

Comment: @Brad:No luck with your coalesce suggestion.

Comment: Step one find the person who put spaces in your column names. Step two punch that person in the face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the Access SQL crosstab query to T-SQL is only part of the process. In order to push all of the processing onto the SQL Server we also need to make sure that all of the dependencies are on the SQL Server, too. (For example, a T-SQL query running on the SQL Server won't be able to pull data from a saved query in Access.)

Following the steps from the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21633961/2144390), we have our table named [Payments] on the SQL Server:

```
Payment Row  Student ID  School  School Service Type  PaymentStartDate  PaymentEndDate
-----------  ----------  ------  -------------------  ----------------  --------------
          1  001         ABC     ED                   2010-01-02        2012-02-04    
          2  001         ABC     ED                   2010-01-02        2010-01-05    
          3  001         ABC     ED                   2010-04-02        2010-05-05    
          4  001         DEF     EZ                   2010-01-02        2012-02-04    
          5  001                 RR                   2012-02-02        2012-02-03    
          6  002         ABC     ED                   2010-02-02        2011-02-03    
          7  002         ABC     EZ                   2010-02-02        2010-06-03    
          8  002         GHI     ED                   2011-02-04        2012-02-04    
          9  003         ABC     ED                   2011-02-02        2012-02-03    
         10  003         DEF     ED                   2010-01-02        2010-08-03    
         11  003                 RR                   2011-02-02        2011-02-03    
         12  004                 RR                   2011-02-02        2011-02-03    
         13  005         GHI     ED                   2010-08-02        2011-02-04    
         14  006         GHI     ED                   2010-08-02        2010-08-02
```

We create the [PaymentsYearMonth] view in SQL Server

```sql
CREATE VIEW PaymentsYearMonth AS
SELECT 
    [Student ID], 
    School, 
    [School Service Type], 
    (Year(PaymentStartDate) * 100) + Month(PaymentStartDate) AS StartYYYYMM, 
    (Year(PaymentEndDate) * 100) + Month(PaymentEndDate) AS EndYYYYMM
FROM Payments
```

The SQL Server also needs to have copies of our [MonthNumbers] table

```
MonthNumber
-----------
          1
          2
          3
          4
          5
          6
          7
          8
          9
         10
         11
         12
```

and our [YearNumbers] table

```
YearNumber
----------
      2009
      2010
      2011
      2012
      2013
```

So now we can create the [MonthsToReport] view. T-SQL doesn't have `DMin()` and `DMax()` functions, so we need to change the query slightly

```sql
CREATE VIEW MonthsToReport AS
SELECT
    yn.YearNumber,
    mn.MonthNumber,
    (yn.YearNumber * 100) + mn.MonthNumber AS YYYYMM
FROM
    YearNumbers AS yn,
    MonthNumbers AS mn
WHERE ((yn.YearNumber * 100) + mn.MonthNumber)>=(SELECT MIN(StartYYYYMM) FROM PaymentsYearMonth)
    AND ((yn.YearNumber * 100) + mn.MonthNumber)<=(SELECT MAX(EndYYYYMM) FROM PaymentsYearMonth)
```

The SQL query to count the distinct rows is exactly the same, so let's create a view for that so when we do the PIVOT in the next step it will be easier to see what's going on

```sql
CREATE VIEW DistinctCountsByMonth AS
SELECT
    YearNumber,
    MonthNumber,
    School,
    [School Service Type],
    COUNT(*) AS CountOfStudents
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            mtr.YearNumber,
            mtr.MonthNumber,
            pym.[Student ID],
            pym.School,
            pym.[School Service Type]
        FROM
            MonthsToReport AS mtr
            INNER JOIN
            PaymentsYearMonth AS pym
                ON mtr.YYYYMM>=pym.StartYYYYMM 
                    AND mtr.YYYYMM<=pym.EndYYYYMM
    ) AS distinctQuery
GROUP BY 
    YearNumber,
    MonthNumber,
    School,
    [School Service Type]
```

Now, if we were doing a crosstab query in Access it would simply be

```sql
TRANSFORM First(CountOfStudents) AS n
SELECT YearNumber, MonthNumber, School
FROM DistinctCountsByMonth
GROUP BY YearNumber, MonthNumber, School
PIVOT [School Service Type]
```

but the PIVOT clause in T-SQL requires that we give it the actual list of column names (as opposed to Access, which can generate the column names automatically). So we'll create a stored procedure on the SQL Server that builds the list of column names, constructs the SQL statement, and executes it:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE DistinctPaymentsCrosstab
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE 
            @ColumnList AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    -- build the list of column names based on the current contents of the table
    --     e.g., '[ED],[EZ],[RR]'
    --     required by PIVOT ... IN below
    --     ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14797796/2144390     
    SET @ColumnList = 
            STUFF(
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME([School Service Type])
                    FROM [DistinctCountsByMonth] 
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 
                1, 
                1, 
                '')
    SET @SQL = '
            WITH rollup
            AS
            (
                SELECT 
                    [School Service Type], 
                    YearNumber, 
                    MonthNumber, 
                    School, 
                    SUM(CountOfStudents) AS n 
                FROM [DistinctCountsByMonth]
                GROUP BY 
                    [School Service Type],
                    YearNumber, 
                    MonthNumber, 
                    School
            )
            SELECT * FROM rollup
            PIVOT (SUM([n]) FOR [School Service Type] IN (' + @ColumnList + ')) AS Results'
    EXECUTE(@SQL)
END
```

Now we can call that stored procedure from Access by using a pass-through query

[image: PassThroughQuery.png]

returning

[image: Results.png]

Answer (score 0):

[See Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21371/SQL-Server-Profiler-Step-by-Step) on creating indexes in SSMS to optimize your most-queried data. (This will increase speed)

[See Here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2023/microsoft-access-pass-through-queries-to-sql-server-in-detail/) regarding pass-through queries.

Both links are very detailed and should help you get to where you need to be and allow you to learn something along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another (1:1) exapmle. The Jet-SQL code:

```
TRANSFORM Count([qTeile-LF-Beziehungen_zuTeileImportListe _PLUS].Warnstufe) AS AnzahlvonWarnstufe
SELECT [qTeile-LF-Beziehungen_zuTeileImportListe _PLUS].Lieferant
FROM [qTeile-LF-Beziehungen_zuTeileImportListe _PLUS]
GROUP BY [qTeile-LF-Beziehungen_zuTeileImportListe _PLUS].Lieferant
PIVOT [qTeile-LF-Beziehungen_zuTeileImportListe _PLUS].Warnstufe;
```

On SQL-Server the code is:

```
SELECT  [Lieferant]
       ,ISNULL([ok], 0)   AS [ok]
       ,ISNULL([W180], 0) AS [W180]
       ,ISNULL([W360], 0) AS [W360]
       ,ISNULL([W720], 0) AS [W720]
FROM  
(
    SELECT  [Lieferant]
           ,[Warnstufe] AS [AnzahlvonWarnstufe]
    FROM [dbo].[VIEW_qTeile-LF-Beziehungen_zuTeileImportListe_PLUS_Warnstufe]    
) src 
pivot
(
    COUNT([AnzahlvonWarnstufe])
    FOR [AnzahlvonWarnstufe] IN ([ok], [W180], [W360], [W720])

) piv;
```

Have fun.